# Unable to receive mails using smtplib as recipient is getting added in bcc list

Tags: python, smtplib

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login("user1@outlook.com", "pass")

body = 'Subject: Mail test .\n\n' + 'Email\'s BODY text' + '\nYour :: Signature/Initials'
server.sendmail("user1@outlook.com","user2@outlook.com",body)
server.quit()
```

I can see the mail sent in user1 sent items but user2 is in bcc list not in to as to shows unknown and mail is not received in user 1 account.

Please help me as what i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib
toaddr = 'someone@gmail.com'
cc = ['alexander@email.com','willow@email.com']
bcc = ['chairman@gmail.com']
fromaddr = 'youremail@email.com'
message_subject = "disturbance in sector 7"
message_text = "Three are dead in an attack in the sewers below sector 7."
message = "From: %s\r\n" % fromaddr
    + "To: %s\r\n" % toaddr
    + "CC: %s\r\n" % ",".join(cc)
    + "Subject: %s\r\n" % message_subject
    + "\r\n" 
    + message_text
toaddrs = [toaddr] + cc + bcc
server = smtplib.SMTP('server',port)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, message)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I can see the message in sent items but is not getting delivered to the recipient,What could be the issue here?

Comment: i can send mail to gmail but not to outlook?Please help me with this

Comment: then you should be configure SMTP settings according to outlook.try to remove the port parameter.